# Trying to use a variable from Pre-Request Script in Test Tab, but getting an undefined error message

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am currently learning Postman and I am trying to understand the following: I am trying to send a POST request and then test the response with some assertions I have written up under the test tab. I have some variables set up in the pre-request tab, which I use in the body when sending the request.  However, one of my tests is failing when trying to make an assertion and I was wondering if somebody could point out what I am doing wrong.

This is my Pre-request script where I set the variables and their values.
[image]

This is the body that I am sending with the POST request
[image]

This assertion is failing. I am getting that `{{randomTitle}}` is not defined.  I thought I could call that variable again since I it is in the Pre-request script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Accessing variables using `{{}}` or `{}` in pre-request script or test script is not supported. Instead, use postman methods to get a variable value, and then use it.

For instance in TestScript

```
var random_title = pm.collectionVariables.get("randomTitle");
```

And then use `random_title`'s value further in a test case.

*Note: if you are using different variables than `collectionVariables`, retrieval syntax would be different.*